# What are the best stats you can roll/reroll for each class?

Tags: realms-of-despair

What are the best stats you can roll/re-roll for each class?  I know the basics, which stats are primary and secondary, but what's the whole picture?

```
Class       Primary  Secondary
Augurer     WIS      LCK
Barbarian   STR      CON
Bladesinger DEX      STR
Cleric      WIS      INT
Druid       WIS      CON
Fathomer    DEX      INT
Mage        INT      WIS
Nephandi    INT      DEX
Paladin     STR      WIS
Ranger      STR      WIS
Thief       DEX      CHA
Vampire     DEX      INT
Warrior     STR      DEX
```

Comment: Do you mean if there are any hard limits imposed by the game itself?

Comment: Well, based on the ease of eq to max mana and hp gains at each level, plus based on what you need to run a strong avatar for that class, what are the minimum stats you need for each, and what are the stats you should max?  For example, a Druid's Wis maxes at 25 and Con maxes at 22, although you cannot roll higher than 18 for either stat when you start a new character.  And to make a druid useful, you need strength, and int as well, as they play into damage and spell damage at avatar, plus carrying capacity for runs.  So you want 13+ str, and 13+ int to start as well. What's the best roll?

Answer (score 1):

Each new character's stats add to a total of 95 between the 9 statistics and range between 9-18 base.

The prevailing opinion is there are certain stats that every class will want to max out, namely strength, dexterity and luck.  Strength affects how much you can carry and dexterity affects things like quaffing potions.  Luck is vague but it's affects things like container scrapping versus breath attacks, saving throws in general, disarm, charm and many other things, according to the SMAUG 1.8 source code.

Here are some suggestions with the notation that stats are easy to get if you play devout and harder when you switch to evil.

```
Class       Suggestion based on mid range avatar gear
Augurer     16 str, 15 WIS, 16 dex, 16 LCK
Barbarian   18 STR, 18 dex, 16 CON
Bladesinger 18 STR, 18 DEX, 15 lck
Cleric      14 str, 14 WIS, 14 INT, 16 dex
Druid       14 str, 14 int, 18 WIS, 13 dex, 18 CON
Fathomer    16 str, 18 DEX, 16 INT
Mage        13 str, 17 INT, 17 WIS, 13 dex
Nephandi    14 str, 18 INT, 18 DEX
Paladin     18 STR, 16 WIS, 15 dex (can only be good aligned, lower strs are ok)
Ranger      18 STR, 15 dex, 16 WIS
Thief       18 str, 18 DEX, 15 lck
Vampire     18 str, 18 DEX, 16 INT (if neutral)
            16 str, 18 DEX, 18 INT (if evil)
Warrior     18 STR, 16 DEX, 15 con
```

This is based on some experience with rerolling and some assumptions.  It's hard to guess what's ideal in every situation in a game so open ended, someone may use a cleric in a very different way than I would and may need different gear to make a different build work.

Additionally I wouldn't want to hand roll any of these combinations, a script is highly advised.  Some of these combos are exceptionally hard for certain races.  In general a "hard" combination is something that when running 8 scripted characters all rerolling takes longer than 1-2 days to roll.

Comment: Character rolling is no longer used on the Realms of Despair, rather players assign points now.  Also important some stats such as CON have undergone improvements to make them more relevant.  Generally a stat below 11 will be considered deficient and may incur a penalty.